# How to do Facebook stream with Caption in Agora?

Tags: java, android, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

Is any option in agora stream with the caption on the Facebook stream URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **addPublishStreamUrl()** to send live streams to Facebook stream. Here is the API doc for that: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_rtc_engine.html#a4445b4ca9509cc4e2966b6d308a8f08f.

You can take a look at this article for more understanding on how to use this API: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/cdn_streaming_android?platform=Android